# Construct a bijection from $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} -\{0\} $ to $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

I have an idea of using the map $[a,b] \mapsto \frac{a}{b}$ where $[a,b]$ are the equilvalence classes of the relation ~ where $(a,b) \sim (c,d) \iff ad=bc$ to find bijection, it seems so trivial I can't figure out a satisfactory proof of bijection.

Comment: Perhaps it is just me misunderstanding, but do you want a bijection $\phi: \mathbb{Z}\times (\mathbb{Z}-\{0\})\to \mathbb{Q}$ or do you first want to impose an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $\mathbb{Z}\times (\mathbb{Z}-\{0\})$ and then find a bijection $\psi: \mathbb{Z}\times (\mathbb{Z}-\{0\})/\!\!\sim \,\to \mathbb{Q}$?

Answer (score 1):

[EDIT: The question has been completely rewritten since the time I wrote this answer.]

Your question is extremely poorly worded, to the point of being unanswerable, since you neglected to specify which function you have in mind. We can't help you show that a specific function is bijective, if you haven't even said what that function is.

That being said, this is a standard exercise so I can sort of fill in the blanks and guess at what you meant to ask. Even after doing so, I believe that what you are trying to show is false. I think you are trying to put an equivalence relation on $\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$, where the elements $(a,c)$ and $(b,d)$ are equivalent if $ad=bc$. The equivalence class of $(a,c)$ would naturally be identified with the rational number $a/c$ - and I think this is the function you have in mind. Except there is a problem: if $c=0$ but $a$ is non-zero, then you would be identifying the equivalence class of $(a,c)$ with $\infty$, which is not an element of $\mathbb Q$. Note that this problem goes away if you restrict to $\mathbb N$ instead of $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Q^+$ instead of $\mathbb Q$, and you do get a bijection in that case.

Comment: Restricting to $\mathbb N$ only makes the problem go away if you use the convention that $0\notin\mathbb N$. Anyway, you can get all of $\mathbb Q$ by using pairs from $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z^+$.